# Why $\prod\limits_{p\leq N}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p^{ks}}=\sum\limits_{n\ge1,P(n)\leq N}\frac{1}{n^s}$?

Tags: number-theory

When we write $p$, it mean that $p$ is prime. Let $P(n)=\max\{p:p\mid n\}$,

We have that $$\prod_{p\leq N}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p^{ks}}=\sum_{k_1,k_2,...,k_{\pi(N)}=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p_1^{k_1s}\cdot ...\cdot p_{\pi(N)}^{k_{\pi(N)}s}}=\sum_{k_1,k_2,...,k_{\pi(N)}=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(p_1^{k_1}\cdot ...\cdot p_{\pi(N)}^{k_{\pi(N)}})^s}=\sum_{\underset{P(n)\leq N}{n=1}}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}.$$

I really don't understand the last equality, could someone give my some explanations ?

Comment: Based on the unicity of prime decomposition $$\prod_{p \le N} (1+p^{-s}+(p^2)^{-s}+(p^3)^{-s}+\ldots) = \sum_{n=1,P(n)\le N}^\infty n^{-s}$$ 
Just work on it until you get it. You can try induction.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to note that "all and only" integers $n$ of the form
$$
p_1^{k_1}\cdots p_{m}^{k_m},
$$
for some nonnegative integers $k_1,\ldots,k_m$, are those ones for which their greatest prime factor $P(n)$ is at most $p_m$.

Answer (score 1):

Here $p_1,...,p_{\pi(N)}$ are all the prime between $1$ and $N$. So you want to sum on $$\{p_1^{k_1}\cdot ...\cdot p_{\pi(N)}^{k_{\pi(N)}}\mid k_i\in \mathbb N, i=1;...,\pi(N)\}.$$

So this is equivalent to sum on all $$\{n\in\mathbb N\mid \text{only primes of $\{p_1,...,p_{\pi(N)}\}$ divide $n$} \},$$
so if we let $P(n)=\max\{p:p\mid n\}$, then

$$\{n\in\mathbb N\mid \text{only primes of $\{p_1,...,p_{\pi(N)}\}$ divide $n$} \}=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid P(n)\leq N\}.$$

Please, let me know if it's not clear.